# What is the Complexity For Checking Which Nodes are Adjacent to a Selected Node?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, big-o

I am currently studying graphs in regards to data structures and algorithms. My question is, what is the complexity to find how many nodes in a graph are adjacent to a selected node?

For example, lets say we have V = 5 nodes in an undirected graph, labeled 1,2,3,4,5, and we want to find the number of nodes adjacent to node 1. The complexity of finding the number of adjacent nodes should be O(V), correct? In the worst case scenario you would have to search all the nodes for an edge to node 1 which is why I think it is O(V). It shouldn't be O(E), where E is the number of edges, because you could have many more edges then there are nodes. Making it unnecessary to search for all the edges in a graph.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: It depends on what data structure the graph is stored in.

Comment: @user207421 based on the adjacency matrix for the graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note: Since you are starting to learn about data structures and algorithms, you should focus on understanding the terms well, before solving any problems. Your question mentions complexity, so I assume you mean [Time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) but there is also [space complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) to take note of, specially if you are studying graph as an example.*

> The (time) complexity of finding the number of adjacent nodes should be O(V),
> correct?

No, not necessarily. You are discussing Big-O, which stands for [worst case time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Worst-case_complexity) and depending on the data structure that you used for representing your graph, it can take `O(n^2)` for [Adjacency Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) and `O(m)` for [Adjacency List](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list) (*assuming the graph has n vertices and m edges*) for constructing the representation.

Now one may think `looking up for adjacent nodes of a vertex` (e.g a method called `getAdjacentNodes()`) on an adjacency matrix / adjacency list may take little time (`O(n)` and `O(1)` respectively), however your program does not have that advantage anymore as your overall time complexity of the program became higher when you were constructing the representation itself (known as bottleneck).

**Update:**

[image]

Following this [article](https://www.programiz.com/dsa/graph-adjacency-matrix), below is an implementation of adjacency matrix for above graph.

```py
class Graph(object):

    # Initialize the matrix (O(n^2))
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.adjMatrix = []
        for i in range(size):
            self.adjMatrix.append([0 for i in range(size)])
        self.size = size

    # Add edges (O(k))
    def add_edge(self, v1, v2):
        if v1 == v2:
            print("Same vertex %d and %d" % (v1, v2))
        self.adjMatrix[v1][v2] = 1
        self.adjMatrix[v2][v1] = 1

    # get adjacent vertices (O(n))
    def get_adjacent_vertices(self, v):
        neighbors = []
        for i in range(self.size):
            if self.adjMatrix[v][i] == 1:
                neighbors.append(i)
        return neighbors

    # Print the matrix
    def print_matrix(self):
        print('\n'.join(['\t'.join([str(cell) for cell in row]) for row in self.adjMatrix]))


g = Graph(5)
g.add_edge(0, 1)
g.add_edge(0, 2)
g.add_edge(1, 2)
g.add_edge(2, 0)
g.add_edge(2, 3)
g.add_edge(3, 4)

g.print_matrix()
# 0  1  1  0  0
# 1  0  1  0  0
# 1  1  0  1  0
# 0  0  1  0  1
# 0  0  0  1  0

print(g.get_adjacent_vertices(2))
# [0, 1, 3]
```

Comment: If the adjacency matrix is already given though then isn't it not correct to include the time required to create it as part of the time complexity for the task?

Comment: @hasManyStupidQuestions then shouldn't the question become `searching a 2D array`?

Comment: Well probably only the OP can clarify what the original intent was. I understand your point though.

Comment: @R__I_. I should have specified. If we're concerned about how long it would take to find vertices adjacent to the selected vertex ONLY, given the adjacency matrix, it should take O(V) because we are only concerned with iterating over the number of nodes. Or perhaps, it can be O(V^2) if the algorithm used doesn't start the search at the specified  vertex.

Comment: @ChicoTabi I'm sorry but why can't you start search at specified vertex? Both for adjacency matrix and list you can. May be you can include your code (alogorithm) in the question as well? May be it's unknown to me but O(V^2) seems too high a price for checking adjacency

Comment: @R__i_ I'm asking generally. I imagine certain algorithms can result in O(V^2). Say you use nested loops to search for adjacency of a vertex that represents the last row of an adjacency matrix, and the outer loop always starts searching from the first row to the last row.

Comment: @ChicoTabi if you specify a vertex, you already know what row you need to search. Please see updated answer for an impl. of adjacency matrix, specifically take note of `get_adjacent_vertices(v)` method. FYI, you won't need a nested for loop as this can be done by one for loop (or a list comprehension).